# How to Configure SSL Certificate and Key on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, server

I am trying to deploy a server (Rasa) on EC2 like [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/configuring-http-api/#configuring-ssl-https). I have it running on an AWS EC2 Instance, but only using HTTP. I want to secure the communication with SSL, but I'm not sure how.

I have made a domain through AWS Route 53, which I connected to my EC2 instance following this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/get-a-domain/). Then, I created a certificate for that domain on AWS Certificate Manager.

Now, I'm unsure of what to do now. How do I create a key corresponding to my SSL Certificate? And how do I configure the certificate and the key to my EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

> And how do I configure the certificate and the key to my EC2 instance?

Sadly, you **can't do this**. The reason is that `AWS Certificate Manager` can only be used on Load Balancers, CloudFront (CF) distributions, API gateway. Thus you can't use ACM cert with your instance directly. You have to front it with, e.g., Application Load Balancer or CF distribution.

If you don't want to use any of the above, you have to get public SSL certificate from **outside of AWS**. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ which is free and also have detailed instructions how to set it up  on various Linux distributions.